# Want Ember.js named outlet to only display on click

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a subnav close to working properly thanks to the help of @intuitivepixel. The problem now is that when I load the root, the subnav is already displaying. The subnav should only be a part of the 'about' section -- the main nav is:

```
about   conditions   programs   testimonials
```

On the index, the root of the app, these are the only links I would like displayed. But when you click 'about' I would like a subnav to display right below the main nav with 'about' set as active and the available sub links as:

```
philosophy    leadership    staff    affiliations
```

Then finally when you click on, say 'philosophy', the philosophy template loads but the 'about' nav is still active, and now the 'philosophy' nav is active.

application.hbs:

```
<div class="row left-nav">
{{#linkTo "index"}}<img class="ew_logo" src="assets/ew.png">{{/linkTo}}
</div>
<div class="row nav">
<div class="large-12 colummns">
    <ul class="inline-list top-nav">
            <li><h6>{{#linkTo "subnav"}}ABOUT{{/linkTo}}</h6></li>
            <li><h6>//</h6></li>
            <li><h6>CONDITIONS</h6></li>
            <li><h6>//</h6></li>
            <li><h6>PROGRAMS</h6><li>
            <li><h6>//</h6></li>
            <li><h6>TESTIMONIALS</h6></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row subnav">
    <div class="large-12 colummns">
        {{outlet 'subnav'}}
    </div>
</div>
{{outlet}}
```

application_route.coffee:

```
Ew.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend(renderTemplate: ->
  @render() 
  # this renders the application template per se
  # and this additional call renders the subnav template into the named outlet
  @render "subnav", #the name of your template
    outlet: "subnav" #the name of the named outlet
    into: "application" #the name of the template where the named outlet should be rendered into
)
```

Thank you!

**EDIT**

I should also add that I don't want 'subnav' to show up in the url when 'about' is clicked. Sorry for all the questions. Just curious if there an ember way to do this without hacking a bunch of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [nested resources](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_nested-resources) for that.

Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/icateme/1/edit) that shows how that would work.

The main part is the routes/resources declaration:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("about", function() {
    this.route("philosophy");
    this.route("leadership");
    this.route("staff");
    this.route("affiliations");
  });

  this.route("conditions");
  this.route("programs");
  this.route("testimonials");
});
```

Here, you define an `about`resource which have a few nested routes.

Then, it's all about [conventions](http://emberjs.com/guides/concepts/naming-conventions/). You just have to properly name your templates.

Here's the `application` template:

```
<h1>MAIN</h1>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>{{#linkTo "about"}}about{{/linkTo}}</li>
    <li>{{#linkTo "conditions"}}conditions{{/linkTo}}</li>
    <li>{{#linkTo "programs"}}programs{{/linkTo}}</li>
    <li>{{#linkTo "testimonials"}}testimonials{{/linkTo}}</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
{{outlet}}
```

Here's the `about` template:

```
<h2>ABOUT</h2>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>{{#linkTo "about.philosophy"}}philosophy{{/linkTo}}</li>
    <li>{{#linkTo "about.leadership"}}leadership{{/linkTo}}</li>
    <li>{{#linkTo "about.staff"}}staff{{/linkTo}}</li>
    <li>{{#linkTo "about.affiliations"}}affiliations{{/linkTo}}</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
{{outlet}}
```

Here's the `about/philosophy` template:

```
<h3>PHILOSOPHY</h3>
```

Ember will automagically add an `.active` class to all the links in the current route.

Comment: I really appreciate this. I had thought earlier that a solution similar to this would work, but what if I want the about subnav to display in the application template, not in the about template?