# jQuery function not firing in Ember app

Tags: jquery, ember.js, handlebars.js

I've been going crazy trying to figure out a way to get a subnav to render properly in ember, see [Want Ember.js named outlet to only display on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18475041/want-ember-js-named-outlet-to-only-display-on-click)

I think I might have found a solution except for that the function won't fire.

In my application_view.coffee I have the following:

```
Ew.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend(didInsertElement: ->
  $(".nav").width $(window).width() - 406
  $(".subnav").width $(window).width() - 406
  $(window).resize ->
    $(".nav").width $(window).width() - 406
    $(".subnav").width $(window).width() - 406

  $ ->
    if document.location.href.indexOf('about') > -1
        $("ul").removeClass("sub-nav-list-hide")
        $("ul").addClass("sub-nav-list-show")
)
```

When I execute

```
document.location.href.indexOf('about') > -1
```

in the console, I get the correct response, true or false depending on whether or not 'about' is in the URL. But the rest of the function won't execute. Not sure if there's something I'm missing regarding jQuery functions and Ember?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is not firing because `didInsertElement` is only invoked once when the view is rendered, but for your use case you need to check everytime the route changes.

That said, assuming you are using the latest ember release, you can observe the `currentRouteName` on your application controller.

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  currentRouteChanged: function() {
    if(this.get('currentRouteName').indexOf('about') > -1) {
      $("ul").removeClass("sub-nav-list-hide");
      $("ul").addClass("sub-nav-list-show");
    }
  }.observes('currentRouteName')
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: So this will not work in rc7? Thanks again for all your help. Do you think this way is acceptable for rendering a subnav? Or is there a better way? Also, just curious, but you are extremely knowledgeable, what resources did you use to learn Ember?

Comment: No, in rc7 you need to observe `currentPath` instead. Well you approach is a bit jQuerysh and there are (nearly) always better ways :) as for what resource I used to learn ember, back in January this year I started to by reading the source code and besides that and being subscribed to repo changes (resulting in a lot of emails on a daily basis I could read) I try to track down every bit of ember related stuff google crawler can find on the web, I must admit that questions here on SO helped me also a lot, because If don't know something - I have to find out to keep peace in my mind :)

Comment: I agree its a bit jqueryish. How would you display a subnav in the application template? I feel like this shouldn't be such a big deal in Ember, but I've been struggling to find an answer to this for days.

Comment: I've implemented this code and it displays the subnav when you click the link, but when you navigate to another page, or hit the back button, it doesn't disappear.

Comment: @reknirt, hhm, I guess it will be more fruitful if you open another question with an appropriate title like 'How to create a sub-navigation in ember.js' and post what you have tried, then I'll try to create a demo if I find time later...